# C++ Strip certain tags + replacing HTML special characters

Tags: c++, regex, boost, replace, strip

I have a problem with striping XML tags(with propeties e.g `<smth a="xxxx">important data</smth>`). To do that I was using this

```
std::string ex = "(&lt;)|(&gt;)|(&amp;)|(&quot;)|(&apos;)";
std::string fmt ="(?1<)(?2>)(?3&)(?4\")(?5')"; // replace just html tags
ex += "|(<a href(.*?)\">)|(</a>)|(<quote(.*?)>)|(</quote>)"; // strip else
boost::regex expr(ex);
std::string s2 = boost::regex_replace(src, expr, fmt, boost::match_default | boost::format_all);
```

but I've noticed it causing memory leaks. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is more efficient way?